# Mongoose query to retrieve sequential documents with the same property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Assume I have a number of JSON documents in a Mongo database, like so (obviously hugely simplified! ;-) ):

```
{ 'value': true }
{ 'value': false }
{ 'value': true }
{ 'value': true }
{ 'value': true }
```

I would like to build a query that retrieves the most recent documents where `value` is equal to `true`. ('Recent documents' are understood to be documents appended to the end.)

The result here should return the last three documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default [`ObjectID`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) in that collection, you can use it to retrieve documents in insertion order:

```
db.collection.find({ value: true }).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(3)
```

Anyway, keep in mind that ordering might not be 100% accurate if multiple documents are inserted within a single second:

> The relationship between the order of `ObjectId` values and generation time is not strict within a single second. If multiple systems, or multiple processes or threads on a single system generate values, within a single second; `ObjectId` values do not represent a strict insertion order. Clock skew between clients can also result in non-strict ordering even for values because client drivers generate `ObjectId` values.

If what you actually want is to get all the documents where `value = true` until you hit the first one where `value = false`, then you need multiple queries:

```
// Get the _id of the most recent document with value = false:

const fromId = db.collection
    .find({ value: false })
    .sort({ _id: -1 })
    .limit(1)
    .toArray()[0]._id;

// Get all the documents with _ids greater than fromId and value = true

db.collection.find({ value: true, _id: { $gte: fromId }});
```

Note that, based on the first query, you might think there is no need to check for `value = true` in the second one, but as those are two separated queries, it is possible that some new documents have been inserted between them.

Alternatively, you might choose not to use `value = true` so that you can check if the result of the second query includes any document with `value = false` as a sanity check. If it does, you just need to remove all the documents that come before the one with `value = false`, and that one itself, and you will have a valid result without running additional queries.

Comment: Thanks, Danziger, but I don't know how many documents there are. In the present case, yes, there are three, but what if in the meantime, a couple of documents with the `true` value have been added? I may edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: `.limit(3)` is only indicating you just want to retrieve the 3 most recent documents with `value = true`. You can just remove the `limit` part and you will get all your documents sorted from most recent to oldest (keeping that consideration about `ObjectId` in mind).

Comment: @jfix I think I got what you meant. Please, take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Danziger, this works fine. I only had to make a minor modification: `toArray()` doesn't seem to be supported (maybe because I'm using Mongoose 5.0.1?). Anyway, replacing it with `.cursor().next()` got me the document. Here's the code I used to check, the document schema is a bit more involved than what I put in my question: https://runkit.com/jfix/5a6e0c79354f1f00128a75f6

Comment: @jfix Great! That's normal, [`toArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) is a method from the native driver's `Cursor` class.